# How to change Google Chrome's address-bar-text font size (the 'https://...')?

Tags: macos, safari, high-sierra, google-chrome, font

How does one change the text for Chrome's address bar font size? I need to make it larger, more readable, especially for high-resolution monitor displays.

This font size is NOT for the displayed web-page content(s).

I'm running macOS 10.12.6, Chrome Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit). I want to do it for macOS 10.13, too.

[image: Chrome-screenshot-1]

Answer (score 2):

Use [TinkerTool](https://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html) to change the [System font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xslpI.png).

Problem is, making larger System fonts [can do wonky things not only in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siJhG.png) but other apps/windows. Other than trying diff font sizes, how can I adjust for this in Chrome? Maybe I can increase the address-bar height somehow - possibly by making larger extension icon sizes, or some other customization settings I've not yet found? Suggestions welcome.

[image: TinkerTool System font]
The following shows an example of problems with System = 24:

[image: wonky font size makes Chrome silly]
(I'm the question author. Default System font size for my MacBook = 13.)

Comment: After some "tinkering," System = 17 works pretty well for me. And it's a decent visual upgrade to see the 'https://...' text better on my 32", 4k display monitors.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to or separately from [my other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/331775/13179), you can [change the display resolution to 'Larger Text', or a similar setting](http://osxdaily.com/2016/05/23/increase-system-text-size-mac-os-x-scaled-resolution/). This also changes the fonts for all screen elements in all applications - which may or may not be desired.

I experience good results when employing both this solution and the one from [my other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/331775/13179).

[image: display-resolution-larger-text-macos]

Comment: Doesn't quite work on external monitors connected via DisplayPort on M1